# How to bind flipping action for CarouselView using mvvm?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I followed [this](https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/) article and implemented CarouselView in my Xamarin forms app but I cant figure out which event or command to bind when it is flipped. I want to execute some code when it is flipped. I can do that using code behind with ItemSelected or PositionSelected but I want this to be done in the ViewModel. And when I try to bind a command on these 2 as below, It throws an exception saying "No Property of name PositionSelected found"

XAML:

```
         <cv:CarouselView  x:Name="list"   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Logs}" PositionSelected="{Binding OnPositionSelected}">
                <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    ...
```

ViewModel:

```
private Command onPositionSelected;

public Command OnPositionSelected
{
    get {
        return onPositionSelected;
    }
    set {               
        onPositionSelected = value;
    }
}
```

and this works without problem

```
  <cv:CarouselView  PositionSelected="OnPositionSelected">
                    <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        ...

  private void OnPositionSelected(object sender, SelectedPositionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.SelectedPosition.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: And what is the Exception it is throwing?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis No Property of name PositionSelected found

Comment: @GeraldVersluis please see my updated question

Comment: Please see my inserted answer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the `PositionSelected` property is bindable and/or takes a `Command`. So you either have to implement an event handler, which casts your `BindingContext` and call the `Command` from there. This would look something like this:

```
private void OnPositionSelected(object sender, SelectedPositionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var param = e. SelectedPosition as string;
    var command = ((FooViewModel)BindingContext).NavigateToSomething;

    if (command.CanExecute(param))
    {
        command.Execute(param);
    }
}
```

But it seems you're using MVVM, so it would be better to implement [Behaviors](https://blog.xamarin.com/turn-events-into-commands-with-behaviors/). There are Xamarin.Forms default behaviors, but I find the [behaviors plugin](https://github.com/corradocavalli/Corcav.Behaviors) by Corrado Cavalli a bit easier to implement. With these Behaviors you can turn `Events` into `Commands` (amongst other stuff)

Install the NuGet package and update your XAML to something like this.

```
<cv:CarouselView  x:Name="list"   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Logs}">
    <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <b:BehaviorCollection>
            <b:EventToCommand EventName="PositionSelected" Command="{Binding OnPositionSelectedCommand}" />
        </b:BehaviorCollection>
    </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
...
</cv:CarouselView>
```

Don't forget to insert the namespace in your page `xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Behaviors;assembly=Xamarin.Behaviors"`

Also there is a `CommandParameter` available in the `b:EventToCommand` with which you can supply a parameter to your invoked Command.

Also check out these [blog](http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=205) [posts](http://blog.masterdevs.com/xf-day-7/) for more information on this.

Comment: Thanks you, this makes sense. one more thing please. what is exactly the difference between PostionSelected and ItemSelected? When I debug them both are called like "OnAppearing" for the next item? Is there any event that will for the current item. Because When I want to make an sqlite insert for the current item, not next one. thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to help! If it has helped you, please mark it as the answer. Both events are similar. The `ItemSelected` can be seen as the `OnAppearing`, so it happens when the new item shows. The `PositionChanged` is probably fired when just that happens. Both do somewhat the same, the timing is different. Play with it a little and see what fires when.

Comment: exactly I debugged both and both are OnAppearing. Do you know if any event exist like OnDissapearing?

Comment: Don't think there is, but `OnAppearing` of the new one you know the old one is disappearing ;)